# How would I make this Racket code DRYer?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm porting a Python script to Racket as a learning experience, and I have this function:

```
(define (check-status)
    (define git [find-executable-path "git"])
    (define-values (ckot out in err)
        (subprocess #f #f #f git "checkout" "-q" "master"))
    (define-values (local lout lin lerr)
        (subprocess #f #f #f git "rev-parse" "@"))
    (define-values (remote rout rin rerr)
        (subprocess #f #f #f git "rev-parse" "@{u}"))
    (define-values (merge-base mbout mbin mberr)
        (subprocess #f #f #f git "merge-base" "@" "@{u}"))
    (display-lines (port->lines mbout))
   (define ports '(ckot out in err local lout lin lerr remote rout rin rerr merge-base mbout mbin mberr))
   (map (lambda (x)
        (cond ((input-port? x) (close-input-port x))
              ((output-port? x) (close-output-port x)))) ports))
```

The problem is that it's not very DRY. Since I'm using a Lisp, and Lisp is known for being able to do crazy things, I want to know if there's a way to take all the subprocess code and extract it so I can do something like:

```
(define (check-status)
    (define commands '(
                        '("checkout" "-q" "master") 
                        '("rev-parse" "@") 
                        '("rev-parse" "@{u}") 
                        '("merge-base" "@" "@{u}"))
    (map currently-immaginary-git-command-fn commands))
```

and end up with a list of the output of each command in the list of commands. How would I do this? Since I'm new to the whole Lisp/Scheme thing, I'm figuring out the syntax as I go and I'm not fully aware of the resources available to me.

Comment: This would be a good question for [StackExchange CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This already has an accepted answer, although @Jonathan is welcome to take his working code and post it to Code Review, if he wants it reviewed

Comment: BTW, the port-closing code won't work: `'(ckot out in ...)` is a list of symbols; it's the same as `(list 'ckot 'out 'in ...)`. You want `(list ckot out in ...)` instead.

Comment: Oh my, thanks. Is there a resource I can look at to see the difference between ' and list?

Comment: A little late, but yes: [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, good for you for wanting to come up with a cleaner solution! You're right that there's a more elegant way to do what you've attempted.

To start, using `subprocess` is almost certainly overkill in your particular use-case. The [`racket/system`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Fsystem%29) module provides a simpler interface that should be sufficient for your needs. Specifically, I'd use the [`system*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._system%2A%29%29) function, which executes a single process with the provided arguments, then prints its output to stdout.

Using `system*`, it's possible to create a very general helper function that can execute a command for a particular executable and returns its output as a string.

```
(define (execute-command proc-name)
  (define proc (find-executable-path proc-name))
  (λ (args)
    (with-output-to-string
     (thunk (apply system* proc args)))))
```

This function itself returns a *new* function when it's called. This means that using it to call a Git command would look like this:

```
((execute-command "git") '("checkout" "-q" "master"))
```

The reason for this will become apparent shortly.

Actually looking at the implementation of `execute-command`, we use [`with-output-to-string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._with-output-to-string%29%29) to redirect all of the output from the `system*` call into a string (instead of just printing it to stdout). This is actually just an abbreviation for using `parameterize` to set the `current-output-port` parameter, but it's simpler.

With this function, we can implement `check-status` very easily.

```
(define (check-status)
  (define commands
    '(("checkout" "-q" "master") 
      ("rev-parse" "@") 
      ("rev-parse" "@{u}") 
      ("merge-base" "@" "@{u}")))
  (map (execute-command "git") commands))
```

Now the reason for having `(execute-command "git")` return a new function becomes apparent: we can use that to create a function which will then map over the `commands` list to produce a new list of strings.

Also, note that the definition of the `commands` list only uses a single `'` at the beginning. The definition you provided would not work, and in fact, the `ports` list you defined in your original implementation is not what you'd expect. This is because `'(...)` is *not* exactly the same as `(list ...)`—they are different, so be careful when using them.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Funny, I figured it'd have something to do with returning a function or macros.