# list of procedure not working? *Important

Tags: racket, procedure

Working on an assignment right now (racket) and came across this problem.

```
> (define a '(even?))
> a
(even?)
> (first a)
even?
> (even? 2)
#t
> ((first a) 2)
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: even?
  arguments.:
```

Why is this not working?
Isn't ((first a) 2) equivalent to (even? 2) ??

Comment: Adam B already answered your question, but the question [What is the difference between `quote` and `list`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) can help you understand why. It explains this problem in much greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(even?)` is equivalent to `(quote (even?))` which returns a list with a symbol `even?` (not the function).

If you want the code you're describing to work you need to have the first define look like `(define a (list even?))` which is a list with the procedure `even?` in it.