# in Scheme, is there syntactical sugar for an ordinary, unquoted list?

Tags: scheme, lisp, syntactic-sugar

In Scheme, if I wanted a list, say (1 2 3), I would just write `'(1 2 3)`. Usually, this is fine, but it is actually equivalent to `(quote (1 2 3))`, which is not exactly the same as `(list 1 2 3)`. An example of when this would give different results:

```
'(1 2 (+ 0 3)) -> (1 2 (+ 0 3))
(list 1 2 (+ 0 3)) -> (1 2 3)
```

Is there a syntactical sugar for the second line here? For vectors there is. For example:

```
#(1 2 (+ 0 3)) -> #(1 2 3)
(vector 1 2 (+ 0 3)) -> #(1 2 3)
```

If there is no such sugar for list, that would be pretty ironic, because lists are used way more often than vectors in Scheme!

Comment: In Racket (my interpreter), `#(1 2 (+ 0 3))` evaluates to `'#(1 2 (+ 0 3))`

Comment: See this question: [What is the difference between quote and list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) and its accepted answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez The same in Guile and Chicken: literal syntax for vectors does not evaluate forms inside.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to evaluate a part of the list, you can use [quasiquoting and unquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html), like this:

```
`(1 2 ,(+ 0 3))
=> '(1 2 3)
```