# Why does the Racket interpreter write lists with an apostroph before?

Tags: scheme, racket

Why is '(1 2 3) written instead of (1 2 3) ?

```
> (list 1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
```

Comment: `(list 1 2 3)` should return `(1 2 3)`. Printing `'(1 2 3)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Racket's default printer prints a value as an expression that would evaluate to an equivalent value (when possible). It uses `quote` (abbreviated `'`) when it can; if a value contains an unquotable data structure, it uses constructor functions instead. For example:

```
> (list 1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
> (list 1 2 (set 3))   ;; sets are not quotable
(list 1 2 (set 3))
```

Most Lisps and Schemes print values using the `write` function instead. You can change Racket's printer to `write` mode using the `print-as-expression` parameter, like this:

```
> (print-as-expression #f)
> (list 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
```

See [the docs on the Racket printer](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html) for more information.