# How to use lambdas from a list in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, higher-order-functions, mit-scheme

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use lambdas that are contained within lists in Scheme. For example, I have the following code:

```
(define abc '((lambda (x) (* x x))))
```

I would like to take the first lambda from the list and apply it to some numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```
(map (car abc) '(1 2 3))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
;The object (lambda (x) (* x x)) is not applicable.
```

But when I try the same thing directly using just the lambda, it works:

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x)) '(1 2 3))
;Value 15: (1 4 9)
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The issue as that you're treating `'((lambda ...))` as if it were the same as `(list (lambda ...))`, but they are radically different. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) and its answer do a good job at explaining why.

Comment: If you're confused about how `quote` works, then you will make many fewer mistakes if you just use `list` everywhere, and never use `quote` for lists at all, only for symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should understand that

```
(lambda () 42)
```

and

```
'(lambda () 42)
```

are not the same thing. The first one when evaluated gives you back a callable object that when called returns 42, the second one when evaluated returns a list where the first element is the symbol `lambda` the second element is an empty list and the third element is the number 42.

Your code is defining `abc` as a list containing a list where the first element is the symbol `lambda`, not a list containing a callable function. For that you need to write

```
(define abc (list (lambda (x) (* x x))))
```

in other words a `lambda` form needs to be **evaluated** to give you a callable function.

Comment: another notation, though less clear in this context, sometimes clearer if used the right way, is to use a quasiquote (back-tic `), which lets you quote a large data structure, but still evaluate parts of it with (unquote ,)

Comment: `(,(lambda (x) (* x x)) ,(lambda (x) x) ,(lambda (x) 5))