# Basic Racket syntax error: application not a procedure

Tags: racket

I get an error message for the code below. It's just a simple syntax error, but as a beginner I'm not sure what's wrong. Anybody know?

```
(define qsort
  (lambda (input-list)

    (define sort-pivot-iter
      (lambda (input-list pivot acc)
        (let ([current             (first input-list)]
          [pivot-less          (first acc)]
          [pivot-greater-equal (first (rest acc))])
            (cond (
                 [(empty? input-list) acc]
                 [(<  current pivot) (sort-pivot-iter (rest input-list) pivot  
                  '((cons current pivot-less) pivot-greater-equal))]
                 [(>= current pivot) (sort-pivot-iter (rest input-list) pivot  
                  '(pivot-less (cons current pivot-greater-equal)))])))))

    (let* ([pivot (first input-list)]
       [pivot-sorted (sort-pivot-iter 
                   (rest input-list) pivot (list empty empty))]
       [left (first pivot-sorted)]
       [right (first (rest pivot-sorted))])
        (cond
          [(< (length input-list) 2) input-list]
          [else (append (qsort left) '(pivot) (qsort right))]))))


(qsort '(2 3 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses around the clauses of the `cond` form, which is causing the entire body to be parsed as a single clause.

This means `[(empty? input-list) acc]` is being treated as an expression (the clause’s condition), which is equivalent to `((empty? input-list) acc)`, since square brackets and parentheses are interchangeable. This attempts to invoke the result of `empty?` as a procedure, which causes the error.

A slightly simplified grammar for `cond` is as follows:

```
(cond cond-clause ...)

  cond-clause = [test-expr body ...]
              | [else body ...+]
```

Notice that each `cond-clause` is wrapped in brackets (or parens), but the clauses themselves are not wrapped in any way. Therefore, your `cond` form should look like this:

```
(cond
  [(empty? input-list) acc]
  [(<  current pivot) (sort-pivot-iter (rest input-list) pivot  
                                       '((cons current pivot-less) pivot-greater-equal))]
  [(>= current pivot) (sort-pivot-iter (rest input-list) pivot  
                                       '(pivot-less (cons current pivot-greater-equal)))])
```

Your code still has some other problems, but those are unrelated to the error message in your question. For one thing, your use of `quote` (aka `'`) here does not make sense to me, so you may also want to read [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list/34984553#34984553) to help with that.