# Evaluating variables in Racket response/xexpr

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a simple bookmarking web-app in Racket.

It's meant to receive a url as a CGI argument, and right now, I'm just trying to confirm I received it by reflecting it back.

```
(define (start request)
  (response/xexpr
   (let* ([bindings (request-bindings request)]
          [url (if (exists-binding? 'url bindings)
                  (extract-binding/single 'url bindings)
                  "NO URL")])
     `(html
       (head (title "TITLE"))
       (body (h2 "TITLE")               
           (p "URL = " url))    
           ))))
```

However, instead of seeing what I expect to see .. which is a page that contains

```
URL = http://google.com
```

I'm seeing

```
URL = &url;
```

Which suggests that url is being quoted literally in the xexpr  (treated as an entity), rather than being evaluated as a variable.

So what am I doing wrong? How do I get url evaluated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `quasiquote` and `unquote` to inject values into a quoted experession, more often seen as their reader abbreviation equivalents, `` ` `` and `,`, respectively. When you use `unquote`/`,` inside of `quasiquote`/`` ` ``, it will evaluate the expression and insert it into the surrounding quotation:

```
> (define url "http://google.com")
> `(p "URL = " ,url)
(p "URL = " "http://google.com")
```

You should put `,` in front of `url` in your template to unquote it.

For a more detailed explanation of quotation and quasiquotation, see [Appendix A of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984553/465378).

Comment: OK I missed the ,  I thought the backtick at the beginning of the expression was sufficient to have variables   evaluated as such.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `,url` :

```
 `(html
       (head (title "TITLE"))
       (body (h2 "TITLE")               
           (p "URL = " ,url))    
           ))))
```

Look for `unquote` in the documentation: [http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html?q=unquote#%28form.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._unquote%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html?q=unquote#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._unquote%29%29)