# How do I factor out xexpr expressions into functions in Racket?

Tags: racket

In my Racket web-server/insta app, I have some repetitive `<div>` HTML that I want to factor out into a separate function and then call it with params to generate the div HTML inside a larger HTML xexpr. All that I get on the web page when I do this are the two parameter strings. How can I factor the `<div>` code out?

I tried simply calling the function from the quoted expression.
I also tried adding a response/xexpr in front of the quoted `<div>` code in the div function, but no go.

;; I want to factor the `<div>` out of this code into a separate function.

```
(define (start request)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html (head (title "Testing")
          (body (form
                  (div ((class "form-group"))
                       (label ((for "public-id")) "Public Id")
                       (input ((type "text")
                               (name  "public-id")
                               (id    "public-id")
                               (placeholder "Enter public id"))))
```

;; I tried doing that with this function, both with and without the "response/xexpr" code.

```
(define (input-field-html fld-name-id fld-caption)

 (response/xexpr

  '(div ((class "form-group"))
        (label ((for fld-name-id)) "Public Id")
        (input ((type "text")
                (name  fld-name-id)
                (placeholder fld-caption))))))
```

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "I tried simply calling the function from the quoted expression"?

Comment: This question might be relavant: [_Evaluating variables in Racket response/xexpr_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646740/evaluating-variables-in-racket-response-xexpr)

Comment: Thanks for your responses Alex and for the link. The answer below works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
#lang web-server/insta


(define (start request)
  (response/xexpr
   `(html (head (title "Testing")
                (body (form
                       ,(input-field-html "public-id" "Enter public id")))))))


(define (input-field-html fld-name-id fld-caption)
  `(div ((class "form-group"))
        (label ((for ,fld-name-id)) "Public Id")
        (input ((type "text")
                (name  ,fld-name-id)
                (placeholder ,fld-caption)))))
```

See:

- [Intermezzo  2: Quote, Unquote](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/i2-3.html)
- [Continue: Web Applications in Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! I'm new to Racket and I see that I will have to spend some time learning macros. Thanks for the links as well!