# Why does '(1 2 3) evaluate to a list en Lisp (Scheme)?

Tags: scheme, lisp, evaluation, quote

The `quote` (`'`) is used to introduce a pre-evaluated value, so `(quote x)` results in the symbol `x` and not what the symbol evalutes to.

Numbers, Booleans, characters and strings are self-evaluating in Scheme, so quoting them doesn't matter.

But why does `(quote (1 2 3))` or `(quote ())` answers `#t` to the predicate `list?`.

Should't the result be a "pre-evaluated" value? But in this case `(1 2 3)` has actually been evaluated to `(list 1 2 3)`?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) contains some good explanations of what `quote` means and how it relates to `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pre-evaluated value

I'm not sure where you got that term from. I've never used it. It's not "pre-evaluated", it's unevaluated.

This is really all works from the fact Lisp (and Scheme) is [Homoiconic](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HomoiconicLanguages): the structure of the program really uses lists and atoms underneath.

`quote` is the dual to `eval`: `(eval (list '+ '1 '2 '3))`  (and since a quoted number is just the number, `(eval (list '+ 1 2 3))` does it as well) is the opposite of `(quote '(+ 1 2 3))`.

**An evaluated list is a call, so an unevaluated call is a list.**

> Should't the result be a "pre-evaluated" value? But in this case (1 2 3) has actually been evaluated to (list? 1 2 3)?

You're missing some parentheses here! You get `(list? '(1 2 3))` (or `(list? (quote (1 2 3))`. That is, `(list? (list 1 2 3))`. Which is true.

You can check the opposite with `(eval (list '+ 1 2 3))`: you get `6`.

Note: Some values just evaluate to themselves (like numbers or functions. You can throw `eval` at it as many times as you want, and it won't change a thing: `(eval (eval (eval 1)))` is just `1`.)

Comment: Edited: It should be list and not list?.

Comment: (eval (list + 1 2 3)) returns an error in my Scheme: "Exception: invalid syntax #<procedure +>"

Comment: you might want `(list '+ 1 2 3)`. Sorry, I only had racket installed.

Comment: Well, I just tried with Chicken Scheme, and `(eval (list + 1 2 3))` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I use Petite Scheme, but lets ignore the implementation details :-)

Comment: Right. Does this seem to make sense?

Comment: Is (eval ..) the same thing as entering an expression at the interpreter prompt?

Comment: Let's say each `eval` removes a level of `quote`. `quote` is an "evaluation barrier", `eval` is an evaluator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122378/discussion-between-ven-and-nlykkei).

Comment: Thank you, Ven. I think I understand it.

Comment: I think you should remove the ' from "quote is the dual to eval: (eval (list + 1 2 3)) is the opposite of (quote '(+ 1 2 3))." - there should not be double quote right?

Comment: `(eval (list + 1 2 3))` should be `(eval '(+ 1 2 3))` or `(eval (list '+ '1 '2 '3))` since how it's now `+` gets evaluated twice.

Comment: @Sylwester Right. Racket doesn't care, but it seems Chicken scheme does.

Comment: @Ven that means rackets procedures are self evaluating, but thats not a portable feature since the reports don't demand this. It's also like some schemes return the value in `display` or perhaps choosing `#f` as the default in `cond` when no `else` is specified. All of them are ok since the spec doesn't specify these.

Comment: @Sylwester answer was edited! Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`(quote (+ 1 2 3))` **=** `'(+ 1 2 3)` **=** `(list '+ '1 '2 '3)` **=** `(list '+ 1 2 3)` (numbers are self-evaluating, i.e. evaluating to self).

`(eval '(+ 1 2 3))` **=** `(+ 1 2 3)` **=** `6`. And `(eval '(1 2 3))` **=** `(1 2 3)` **=** *error*.

The first identity is just syntactical. The central identity here is the second one, `'(+ 1 2 3)` **=** `(list '+ '1 '2 '3)`. It holds because *everything is evaluated in Lisp*, but before that, it must be ***read***. Which means, *converted* from textual source code to actual data structures.

Since `( ... )` parentheses denote *lists*, reading `( ... )` *forms* creates *lists*. Then, evaluating the *quoted* form just returns that form *as is* (i.e. non-evaluated). The token `+` gets read as a *symbol* `+`; the literals `1, 2, 3` get read as *numbers* `1, 2, 3`. So the end result *is the same* as the result of evaluating the form `(list '+ '1 '2 '3)`.

And of course all this still applies without the `+` inside, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The quote introduces an *unevaluated* value, not *pre-evaluated*, whatever that means.

When the expression `(quote X)` is treated as a form to be evaluated, it simply evaluates to `X` itself. `X` is not treated as a form to be evaluated to a value, but rather the resulting value is the **syntax** `X` itself.

Quote is a way of the program expressing, "I want to use a piece of my own syntax as a value". And that's precisely what a "literal" is in computer science: a piece of program text reflected back into the program as a run-time value.

In Lisp, atoms other than symbols denote themselves when evaluated. The syntax `3` evaluates to the integer `3`. They are the same thing: Lisp syntax is a data structure, and in that data structure, an integer literal `3` is already represented by the object that it denotes.

Thus, *under evaluation*, there is no difference between `(quote 3)` and just `3`. "Give me the syntax 3 itself" and "give me the value of the syntax 3" are the same: just 3.

Under `(quote (1 2 3))`, the syntax being quoted is `(1 2 3)`. That syntax *is* the list object that it looks like; quote just regurgitates it. If were to evaluate the `(1 2 3)` form, it would be an error: it looks like `1` is being used as an operator or function, with arguments `2` and `3`. When `quote` is itself evaluated, it suppresses this evaluation and just yields the `(1 2 3)` as-is.

Because the `(1 2 3)` is a piece of the program syntax, however, there is a restriction in the language that this list may not be modified. An operation like `(inc (car (quote (1 2 3))))` which tries to change the list to `(2 2 3)` invokes undefined behavior.  Essentially, the program is trying to modify its own syntax; if for a moment we disregard the additional complexity that Lisp is a compiled language, this is *de facto* self-modifying code.