# How to cons an argument to every list in a list of lists?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm trying to take in an argument A and a list L in the function`(consToAll A L)` and cons the argument into every sublist of that list.

What is the best way of going about this?

**This is the desired output:**

If L is `( (1) (2) (3) )`
then `(consToAll 'a L)` 
returns:

`( (a 1) (a 2) (a 3) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Treat 'a as a variable var
answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840761/how-can-i-apply-each-element-in-a-list-to-a-function-in-scheme/43043370#43043370)

replace f with var and funtion call `(f (...))` with  `(cons var (car L))`

Answer (score 0):

R5RS/R6RS/R7RS have a built in 'map' procedure which will map over your list L.  The easiest approach is to use that to cons A into each sublist.

**Edit**: Incidentally, be aware that your consToAll procedure will not as you think return `'( (a 1) (a 2) (a 3) )`, which is a literal constant, but will return a list of lists `( (a 1) (a 2) (a 3) )`.  See [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) .