# How can I apply each element in a list to a function in scheme?

Tags: list, scheme

The function applyToAll is suppose to take in a function and a List, then take the car of the list and apply each element to the fuction.

This is what I have worked out so far:

```
(define applyToAll(lambda (f L)
                (cond
                  ((null? L)       '())
                  (#t              (cons (L) (applyToAll f(car L))))
                  )))
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. A fuction call would look like

```
(applyToAll  (lambda (n) (* n n))    '(1 2 3) )
```

and it would return

```
(1 4 9)
```

Instead it returns: function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received (list 1 2 3)

Any help as to why my code is not working?

Thanks

Comment: Is `L` a list of a function? I see it be used as both.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to implement `map`.

The error you are getting is because you are calling a list as though it's a function `(lst1)`

`( )` this means [function call in scheme](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax-overview.html#%28part._.Function_.Calls__.Procedure_.Applications_%29)

You are making the same mistake here:

```
 (#t              (cons (L) (applyToAll f(car L))))
```

the right way to apply is:

```
(function arg0 arg1 ... argn)
```

You need to apply f to each element in the list like so:

```
(cons (f (car L)) (applyToAll f (cdr L))))
```

OR just use [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29):

```
(map proc lst ...+)
```

gl