# Scheme : How to quote result of function call?

Tags: scheme, racket, quote

Is it possible to quote result of function call?

For example

`(quoteresult (+ 1 1)) => '2`

Comment: Althought it is a very basic question, it is very hard to google any learning materials for scheme.

Comment: [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org).

Answer (score 2):

At first blush, your question doesn’t really make any sense. “Quoting” is a thing that can be performed on datums in a piece of source code. “Quoting” a runtime value is at best a no-op and at worst nonsensical.

The example in your question illustrates why it doesn’t make any sense. Your so-called `quoteresult` form would evaluate `(+ 1 1)` to produce `'2`, but `'2` evaluates to `2`, the same thing `(+ 1 1)` evaluates to. How would the result of `quoteresult` ever be different from ordinary evaluation?

If, however, you want to actually produce a `quote` *expression* to be handed off to some use of dynamic evaluation (with the usual disclaimer that [that is probably a bad idea](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html)), then you need only generate a list of two elements: the symbol `quote` and your function’s result. If that’s the case, you can implement `quoteresult` quite simply:

```
(define (quoteresult x)
  (list 'quote x))
```

This is, however, of limited usefulness for most programs.

For more information on what quoting is and how it works, see [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list/34984553#34984553).

Comment: I  need to quote the result because I am building a a quoted representation of scheme program based on input. I will eval it once it is built. Before that happens, I have to quote every list inside to make sure the eval function doesn't try to apply the list head on its tail.

Comment: @FordO. So you are saying you want the result to be the *list* `(quote 2)`? That is, the result of evaluating the expression `(list 'quote 2)`?

Comment: @FordO. Why do you evaluate the forms in the first place? If you nkow what to do `quoteresult` on I guess you could just skip evaluating them in the first place?