# Enforce strurct-constructor evaluation in Racket

Tags: structure, racket, lazy-evaluation

By following code:

```
(struct int (num) #transparent)

(list (int 3) (int 5)) ;; case-1
'((int 3) (int 5))     ;; case-2
```

the case-1 prints `(#(struct:int 3) #(struct:int 5))`,
but the case-2 prints `((int 3) (int 5))`.

How can I deal with the second one as a `struct:int list`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
'((int 3) (int 5))
```

is more or less equivalent to:

```
(list (list 'int 3)  (list 'int 5))
```

So if you want to create a list with a structure as an element, either use `list` directly or ... you can use quasiquote:

```
`(,(int 3) ,(int 5))
```