# racket: equivalent to np.zeros((n, m))

Tags: python, numpy, lisp, racket, backquote

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  Maybe a misplaced backquote.

#### The racket code:

```
(require math/array)
(define mask_cube
  (let ([leng 5])
    `(make-array #(,leng ,leng) 0)))
```

#### What I want it to do, written in python:

```
np.zeros((5,5))
```

Why isn't the comma working like I think it should?  If there's a more elegant way to solve the problem, please let me know.  Mostly I just want my pretty, short `np.zeros()` function

Moreover, if there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding about backquote, commas, or racket (or even Lisp in general), please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want `eval` here. Rather, you are quoting too much; the simple solution to your problem is to move the `` ` `` inwards to the appropriate place:

```
(define mask_cube
  (let ([leng 5])
    (make-array `#(,leng ,leng) 0)))
```

However, I’d generally avoid quotation if you’re a beginner; it is more complicated than it needs to be. Just use the `vector` function instead, which is easier to understand:

```
(define mask_cube
  (let ([leng 5])
    (make-array (vector leng leng) 0)))
```

For an in-depth treatment of quotation (with quasiquotation at the end), see [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list).

Comment: I like the brevity of the backquote.  Moreover, I've done a little lisp before, just out of practice.  Thanks for the revision!

Answer (score -1):

Wow, do I feel stupid.  It's always the same thing: what's evaluated vs. what's just a list of symbols.  The answer (see the `eval`):

```
(define mask_cube
  (let ([leng 5])
    (eval
      `(make-array #(,leng ,leng) 0))))
```

Still open to other answers that are coded with better style and am looking to modify this into a function/macro that translates `np.zeros()` and `np.ones()` into Lisp

Comment: To a good first approximation if you are using `eval` you are making a mistake.

Comment: It's interesting to think how you would do this in python.  I think it is `eval("np.zeros([{}, {}])".format(5, 5)`.  I think that gets across how horrible `eval` is.