# "Quote" showing up in output while appending with fold-left in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, foldleft

I'm attempting to concatenate lists in scheme using fold-left and append (for usage in a bigger function). However, I keep getting outputs that look like this:

```
=> (0 quote (1) quote (2))
```

This is my code:

```
(fold-left (lambda(a b) (append a b)) '(0) '('(1) '(2)))
```

Why wouldn't this work exactly the same as:

```
(define x (append '(0) '(1)))
(define y (append x '(2)))
y
```

This code outputs a simple list:

```
(0 1 2)
```

Isn't fold-left doing the exact same as the second code block?
What can I change to get a simple list output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting inside quoted data. When Scheme encounters `(quote x)`, or `'x` for short, it evaluates it to the argument **unchanged**..

```
'('(1) '(2)))
```

Is short for:

```
(quote ((quote (1)) (quote (2))))
```

And as by my stated evaluation rules it should evaluate to:

```
((quote (1)) (quote (2)))
```

Thus if you take `caar` or that quoted expression you should get the symbol `quote`:

```
(caar '('(1) '(2)))
; ==> quote
```

If you were no intended to have those quotes in the data structure then you need to not have them in the expression, like:

```
'((1) (2))
```

**NB:** There is a language related to Scheme, called Racket, it's default output in their REPL is **not** the value itself but an expression that would evaluate to that value. This is usually confusing even for seasoned schemers. It's like asking someone "what is 3 plus 4" and answer `1 plus 6`.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation. This is one of the more confusing scheme topics for me.