# How can you put structure objects into a list?

Tags: list, scheme, structure

```
#lang Scheme

(define-struct storeItem (id des cost))

(define redApple (make-storeItem 0 "red delicious apple" 1.99))
(define chickenLeg (make-storeItem 1 "boned chicken" 2.99))
(define porkLoin (make-storeItem 2 "processed pork" 4.99))
(define milkD (make-storeItem 3 "vitamin d milk" 3.99))
(define baguetteBread (make-storeItem 4 "french bread" 0.99))
(define orangeJuice (make-storeItem 5 "fruit juice drink)" 1.49))
(define beanCan (make-storeItem 6 "beans in a can" 2.49))

(define masterList '(redApple chickenLeg porkLoin milkD baguetteBread 
   orangeJuice beanCan))
```

I am trying to get a list of objects from my structure and I am unsure of the correct syntax. Below is what I tired

```
(storeItem-des (car masterList)
```

I was expecting `"red delicious apple"`

But I get

```
storeItem-des: contract violation
expected: storeItem?
given: redApple
```

It seems like it is returning `redApple`, which seems correct. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This problem is answered by [What is the difference between `quote` and `list`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a list of symbols, not `storeItem`s.

`'(x y z)` is equivalent to `(list 'x 'y 'z)`, not `(list x y z)`. So if you want to create a list containing the values of the variables `x`, `y` and `z`, you need to use the latter.

Comment: Ah thank you for that.

    application: not a procedure;
    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
     given: #<storeItem>
     arguments...:

This is what I get whenever I change the list type.

Comment: @Jonnyutah For which code do you get that error message?

Comment: @Jonnyutah Did you write `(list redApple chickenLeg ...)`?

Comment: @Jonnyutah It sounds like you forgot to put `list` at the beginning.

Comment: @Barmar If I create (list 1 2 3) 
How am I navigating that list if there is no name for it? Thanks!

Comment: @Jonnyutah It's in the `masterList` variable. `(define masterList (list redApple chickenLeg ...))`

Comment: @Barma 
Thank you! I was able to get it.

I used (define masterList (list element0 element1....element n))