# How can I check if a list is a list of lists?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to check if a parameter before use it in a function with racket. This parameter must be a list of lists.

I have tried:

```
(andmap (lambda (x) (not (and (list? x) (not (pair? x))))) lst)
```

with:

```
(define lst '('(a) '(b) '(c)))
```

But it fails because `(pair? '(a))` is true. With `pair?` I'm trying to avoid `(a . 1)` dotted pairs because `(list? (a . 1))` is also true.

How can I check if a list is a list of lists and doesn't contains dotter pairs?

Comment: Wait, why is `(list? '(a . 1))` true? When I evaluate that I get false

Comment: @AlexKnauth Maybe, I make a mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

1. To check if a list is a list of lists, you can simply write

   ```
   (define (list-of-lists? v)
     (and (list? v) (andmap list? v)))
   ```

   which first checks if the value is a list, then checks if all its elements are lists.
2. If you are doing this because a function should *only* accept a list of lists, and other values are illegal, then you should make things easier for yourself by using [Racket’s contract system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html) instead of doing the validation yourself:

   ```
   (require racket/contract)

   (define/contract (f lst-of-lsts)
     (-> (listof list?) any/c)
     #| do something here |#)
   ```
3. You, like many people exposed to it for the first time, seem to have some confusion about how `quote` works. You probably mean to write `'((a) (b) (c))`, not `'('(a) '(b) '(c))`. Please read [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list/34984553#34984553), or just use the `list` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried `(list-of-lists? '())` and it returns true. I'm going to modify it to return false.