# How to get the first list from a lists of lists?

Tags: racket

So I am having a list of lists. Let's say is '('(1 2) '(3 4)) and if I apply car the result is going to be ''(1 2). What could I use in order to obtain '(1 2).

> (car '('(1 2) '(3 4)))
>   ''(1 2)

Comment: You're double-quoting the nested lists. Try `(car '((1 2) (3 4)))`.

Comment: @user633183 is right. However, if you're new at this, it might be better to avoid quote entirely and just use `list` instead. Like `(car (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))`. See [_What is the difference between quote and list?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) for more explanation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'expression` evaluates to `expression` verbatim whatever `expression` is. However Racket REPL has a weird visualization that is doesn't really print the result but rather an expression that evaluates to the same result. Thus REPL will print `'expression` even though the result was `expression`. Evaluating the REPL output then always prints the same again.

So imagine you do `'(1 2)` you get `'(1 2)` back and make the assumption that that `'` somehow is part of the data and try to do `'('(1 2) '(3 4))` instead of `'((1 2) (3 4))`. Now since `'x` is reader sugar for `(quote x)` you will have made `'((quote (1 2)) (quote (3 4)))` withe `quote` being just symbols and not code.

If you really want `(1 2)` from it you need to do car,cdr,car or `cadar` for short:

```
(cadar '((quote (1 2)) (quote (3 4)))) 
; ==> (1 2) , but racket will print '(1 2)
```

If you didn't really want the extra lists but just that the data was `((1 2) (3 4))` you did correct:

```
(car '((1 2) (3 4))) 
; ==> (1 2) , but racket will print '(1 2)
```

If you `display` the value it will actually print the correct result: `(display '(1 2))` prints `(1 2)` and not `'(1 2)`.

There is a setting to turn off the confusion. In the dropdown in the bottom where you can select `choose language` and under "The racket language" you have options on the right side where you can change "output style" to `write`. Now it will print `(1 2)` rather than an expression that evaluates to `(1 2)` in the racket language too.