# compose given a list of functions

Tags: racket

With some test procedures:

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x) (+ x 1))
(define (bar x) (* x 2))
(define (baz x) (+ x 3))
```

I can "manually" use `compose` to get the right result:

```
((compose foo bar baz) 1)    ;; works
```

...but is there a way to use `compose` with a list?  The closest I can get is a quoted list, and I'd prefer not to use eval if I don't have to.

```
(define test-funcs '(foo bar baz))
((compose test-funcs) 1)     ;; expected: procedure? given: '(#<procedure:foo> #<procedure:bar> #<procedure:baz>)
((compose . test-funcs) 1)   ;; #%app: bad syntax
`((compose . ,test-funcs) 1) ;; almost: '((compose foo bar baz) 1)
```

Comment: Yes, with `(apply compose test-funcs)`. However, you also have another problem, with using `quote` to create a list, where you should use `list` instead. So `(define test-funcs (list foo bar baz))` and `(apply compose test-funcs)`. If you're confused about why, see [_What is the difference between quote and list?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Comment: That's perfect, I'd accept it as an answer if I could.  Thanks for the other help, very enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two options to solve such problem:

1) `((apply compose (list foo bar baz)) 1)`

2) `` ((eval `(compose foo bar baz)) 1) ``