# `or...equal`? clause and list membership check not returning the same results?

Tags: lisp, racket

I am working through the [Beautiful Racket stacker tutorial](https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/the-expander.html) and while coding an expander I have the following bit of code from the tutorial that works

```
(define (handle [x #f])
  (cond
    [(number? x) (push-stack! x)]
    [(or (equal? * x) (equal? + x))
     (push-stack! (x (pop-stack!) (pop-stack!)))]))
```

I see that `or` expression and think "oh, I can clean that up with a list membership check" so then I try

```
(define (handle [x #f])
  (cond
    [(number? x) (push-stack! x)]
    [(member x '(+ *))
     (push-stack! (x (pop-stack!) (pop-stack!)))]))
```

and find that doesn't work at all - that `cond` branch never runs.

To the best of my understanding this should work...so clearly my understanding is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: You want `(member x (list + *))`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list

Comment: `*` and `+` are evaluated in the original code, which compares `x` to values of their bindings; but you have them quoted in a list, so you're comparing `x` to the `*` and `+` symbols themselves.

Comment: The "correct" logic is dubious. Expanders shouldn't be looking at the run-time bindings of symbols.  Also, the code leaves me questioning how lexical scoping is handled. That is to say, what if `(+ a b c)` occurs in a lexical scope where `+` isn't the global one?  An expander needs to take an environment as an argument.

Comment: well this *is* chapter 1 @Kaz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In here, you're testing `x` against the actual *procedures*:

```
(or (equal? * x) (equal? + x))
```

Whereas in here, you're testing `x` against a couple of *symbols*:

```
(member x '(+ *))
```

The above line expands to `(list '+ '*)`. To make an equivalent comparison, you'd have to do this instead:

```
(member x (list + *))
```

Comment: oh interesting, yes that makes sense - I just started believing that `'(foo bar)` and `(list foo bar)` are the same thing but yeah...I don't know why I became convinced of that. Probably just cause I was playing around with it in the terminal and started making assumptions

Comment: @GeorgeMauer have you seen [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list) Interesting that you thought quote and list were the same based on terminal output... good to know for designing future terminal-printing conventions