# Mapping to a nested list, function applies to quote

Tags: racket

I have something like this

```lisp
(map (lambda (l) (apply + l)) '('(1 2) '(3 4)))
```

I expect `'(3 7)`, however I get an error saying that the applied function gets applied to a quote.
Why does this happen?

Comment: When I was a beginner in racket I did have this issue, so it is useful for newcomers to racket. Don't know why it was downvoted :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list I had was equivalent to

```
(list (quote (list 1 2)) (quote (list 3 4)))
```

and not

```
(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

The list was malformed. For the difference between list and quote see this post:  [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list/34984553#34984553).

A proper way to do nested loop is like `'((1 2) (3 4))`.