# Scheme - list passed into function returning empty

Tags: list, parameters, scheme

I am trying to define a helper function that takes an integer and a list as parameters and produces cartesian product of the integer and the list.

I believe I have the logic figured out. But when I test my code and pass a list into the function, the function returns an empty list.

```
    (define (helper element set)
    (cond 
        ((null? set) '())
        (cons '(element (car set)) (helper element (cdr set))) 
    )
)
```

For example, when I run (helper 5 '(6 8 9)) it returns an empty list.

I can't figure out why, but I think it has something to do with passing an integer with a list as parameters but I can't find anything to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for `cond`. The format is

```
(cond (test1 then1)
      (test2 then2)
      ...)
```

There is no special allowance that the last case doesn't need a test. So when you write

```
  (cond 
    ((null? set) '())
    (cons '(element (car set)) 
          (helper element (cdr set))))
```

your test is the symbol `cons`, and your then-expression is "evaluate `'(element (car set))`, throwing the result away, and then evaluate and return `(helper element (cdr set))`" (there is an implicit `begin` around the expressions in the `then` part of a `cond`). Thus, `helper` always just recurses down to an empty set eventually, and then returns it, making no changes to it.

What you meant to do instead was use something that's always true as your last test, and then use the `cons` form as the body. Traditionally `else` is used for this, although `#t` is also fine:

```
(define (helper element set)
  (cond 
    ((null? set) '())
    (else (cons '(element (car set)) 
                (helper element (cdr set))))))
```

You will then discover another problem, which is that you meant to construct a list containing the values referred to by `element` and `(car set)`, not to quote that list. [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34984552/625403) will help you understand what's doing on there.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(define (helper element set)
  (map (lambda(x) (cons element x)) set))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In this case, I was trying to avoid using lambda expressions. But this works well too.