# Empty and '() in function not equal

Tags: racket

i am learning racket for my course and while going through solutions to an assignment, I found that a function doesn't return true, when comparing empty and '()

Here is the output I'm getting:

```lisp
(lst-contains? '(1 2 3 ()) '())      ; output: #t
(lst-contains? '(1 2 3 ()) empty)    ; output: #t
(lst-contains? '(1 2 3 empty) empty) ; output: #f (unexpected!)
(lst-contains? '(1 2 3 empty) '())   ; output: #f (unexpected!)
```

Here's my definition of `lst-contains?`:

```lisp
(define (lst-contains? lst element)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) #f]
    [(equal? (first lst) (element)) #t]
    [else (lst-contains? (rest lst) element)]))
```

Thanks : )

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: is it against the forum guidelines to post code screenshots ? (I am new to stackoverflow) ?

Comment: No it isn't but you can't eaasily copy the code and test it for finding a solution.

Comment: this question/answer is related: [_What is the difference between quote and list?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that `quote` (or `'`) "distributes" across a list. So, when you write `'(1 2 3 empty)`, you're actually creating something that's equivalent to `(list 1 2 3 'empty)` *not* `(list 1 2 3 empty)`.

You can check for yourself that this is the case by looking at the result of:

```lisp
(list-ref '(1 2 3 empty) 3)      ; output: 'empty
(list-ref (list 1 2 3 empty) 3)  ; output: '()
```

Answer (score 0):

In racket they are equal:

```
(define (lst-contains lst element)
  (cond
    ((empty? lst) #f)
    ((equal? (first lst) element) #t)
    (else (lst-contains (rest lst) element))))

(lst-contains '(1 2 3 ()) empty) ; -> #t
```

Tested in DrRacket.

Note that `'(1 2 3 empty)` is different from `'(1 2 3 ())` since in the first case `empty` is taken as a symbol.