# drakma: How to pass JIRA API token for requests?

Tags: common-lisp, drakma

When I do the following, passing my [JIRA API token](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/) ...

```
curl --verbose --request GET \
     --url 'https://myJira.atlassian.net/....' \
     --user 'my_email@domain.com:my_jira_api_token' ...
```

... the operation succeeds and I see one of the headers was:

```
Authorization: Basic encodedAuthInfoHere
```

How would I do the same with [Drakma](https://edicl.github.io/drakma/)? `:basic-authorization` takes a **list** of username and *password*. But JIRA says [basic auth has been deprecated.](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/)

```
(drakma:http-request url
                     :method :get
                     :basic-authorization '(email passwd)
                     ...
```

Is there a way to perform the same encoding that curl used, and add the header explicitly when calling `http-request`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like for curl, Drakma's password can be whatever you want it to be, so you can insert the jira token as in you did with curl.

Would

```
(setf drakma:*header-stream* *standard-output*)
(drakma:http-request "https://myJira.atlassian.net/...."
  :method :get
  :basic-authorization '("my_email@domain.com" "my_jira_api_token"))
```

spark joy?

I'd expect drakma to create a string `my_email@domain.com:my_jira_api_token`, base64-encode it,
and append it to "`Authorization: Basic` ",
so you'd get a header like this:

```
Authorization: Basic bXlfZW1haWxAZG9tYWluLmNvbTpteV9qaXJhX2FwaV90b2tlbg==
```

If your curl example is complete, Drakma should get you as far as curl does.

Comment: Ah. When I used `quote` to construct the basic-authorization list out of my vars, `quote` kept them as symbols instead of evaluating them to be strings. When I used `list` instead, it worked as advertised. So that, plus the idea that the API token could be passed as the "password" was what I was missing. Thank you for the help! Related content: `quote` vs `list` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984553 (It's for Scheme, but at the SBCL REPL, the behavior of `list` vs `quote` seems to be similar enough)

Comment: There's also the backquote, which allows you to ask for evaluation by inserting a comma in front of a symbol or expression.  See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `:parameters` to the request:

```
USER> (drakma:http-request "http://example.com"
                           :method :get
                           :parameters '(("user" . "token")))
```

The reply is:

```
"<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" conten...[sly-elided string of length 1256]"
200 (8 bits, #xC8, #o310, #b11001000)
((:AGE . "507992") (:CACHE-CONTROL . "max-age=604800")
 (:CONTENT-TYPE . "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
 .....)
#<URI http://example.com/?user=token>
#<FLEXI-STREAMS:FLEXI-IO-STREAM {101D4A3723}>
T
"OK"
```

In particular, the 4th returned value, the URI the reply comes from, is:

```
http://example.com/?user=token
```