# Quoting a function name then using it

Tags: racket

I'm writing a program to log to various places.  In it I have some log functions:

```
(define (write-to-file destination content)
      (with-output-to-file destination
          (λ ()
           (displayln 
            content))
        #:mode 'text #:exists 'append))

(define (write-to-port destination content)
  (displayln content destination))
```

I want to use these functions at run-time.  So I have made a list of lists to hold my configuration:

```
(define log-destinations
  '((write-to-file "my.log")
    (write-to-port (current-error-port))))
```

So I have a function that recursively consumes the list `log-destinations`:

```
(define (send-log-content content destinations)
  (unless (null? destinations)
    (let ([ destination (car destinations)])
      (#%app (car destination) (cadr destination) content)) 
    (send-log-content content (cdr destinations))))
```

However at runtime I'm getting:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 'write-to-file
  arguments...:
   "my.log"
   "[info] web: 2021/03/21 16:26:35 +11:00 /\n"
  context...:
```

Which suggests I've not quoted the function name properly.  So how do I quote the function name appropriately in `log-destinations` so it can be called correctly at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the list literal here:

```
(define log-destinations
  '((write-to-file "my.log")
    (write-to-port (current-error-port))))
```

`write-to-file` and `write-to-port` are symbols, and `(current-error-port)` is a quoted list. You need the sublists in `log-destinations` to contain the *procedures* `write-to-file` and `write-to-port`. Further, you need to actually complete the evaluation of `(current-error-port)` to get the error port, which is to say that you need to evaluate the arguments within your lists.

Quoting a list to create a list literal means that the arguments will not be evaluated when the list is created. But, you can use the `list` procedure to create lists while evaluating the arguments:

```
(define log-destinations
  (list (list write-to-file "my.log")
        (list write-to-port (current-error-port))))
```

Alternatively, you could use the backquote syntax, i.e., [quasiquotation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html?q=quasiquote#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29). Quasiquotation allows you to create a list template with some control over how the list members are evaluated. Use a backquote to quasiquote a list, then place a comma before arguments which should be evaluated:

```
(define log-destinations
  `((,write-to-file "my.log")
    (,write-to-port ,(current-error-port))))
```

It isn't clear to me why you are using `#%app`; my guess is that you were thinking of `(current-error-port)` as a list in the procedure application. With the above changes you should be able to change the procedure call to:

```
((car destination) (cadr destination) content)
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list

Comment: Thanks @SoraweePorncharoenwase -- that's a good resource

Comment: Indeed @adabsurdum the #%app wasn't required.  Thanks.