# pass a lambda function to parameters of a function getting it with (car (cdr params) )

Tags: scheme, racket

im trying to get a lambda function from this list of lists '((0 4) (lambda (x) (+ x 100)))

if i do (car (cdr list) ) i get (lambda (x) (+ x 100)), and im using (car (cdr list) ) to get the lambda function to the parameters of another function that uses it but i get the error

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (lambda (x) (+ x 100))
```

If instead of (car (cdr list) ) i write (lambda (x) (+ x 100)) it works, but i need to get it from the second element of the list of lists

Comment: You don't have a function, you have a bunch of symbols...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between quote and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list)

Comment: how would i transform this symbols to an actual lambda function that i can use in another function? im trying with let and define but it doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

The second entry in the list `'((0 4) (lambda (x) (+ x 100)))` is a list of the symbol `lambda` the list `(x)` and the list `(+ x 100)`.
This is because the expression `(lambda (x) (+ x 100))` is not evaluated due to the leading quote.

When the list is defined using  `` `((0 4) ,(lambda (x) (+ x 100))) `` the lambda expression is evaluated. Now the list contains `(0 4)` as the first entry and a function as the second. Then the second entry can be called as the following example demonstrates:

```lisp
(define lst `((0 4) ,(lambda (x) (+ x 100))))
(print ((car (cdr lst)) 10))
```