# Racket - difference between list and '()?

Tags: racket

I don't really understand the difference between list and '(). I thought they did the same but I get an error when I use list with the following code.

```
(define doubleElements (lambda (ls) (if (empty? ls) ls
                                      (cons (* 2 (first ls)) (doubleElements (rest ls))))))
```

Could anyone tell me why and what I should change so both list and '() work. Thank you

(doubleElements '(1 2 3 4 5)) = '(2 4 6 8 10)

(doubleElements list(1 2 3 4 5)) = application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: 1
(pointing at (1 2 3 4 5) if it helps)

Comment: "application: not a procedure" You're doing the same thing that you were doing in your now deleted [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440625/racket-application-not-a-procedure).

Comment: Did you write that `doubleElements` function or was it provided to you? The latter is the only reason I can figure for you not being able to use valid function call syntax elsewhere, since that code is fine...

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list

Comment: it's `(list 1 2 3 4 5)` that creates the same as `'(1 2 3 4 5)` while `list (1 2 3 4 5)` is two expressions. One that evaluates to a procedure object and one where the number 1 is tried called as a procedure. It will always fail to call a number as a procedure.

Comment: You have never seen an example of using `list` that looks like `list (argument argument ...)`. They have all looked like `(list argument argument ...)`.